# Different upsert behavior on Cosmos DB vs MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm running into an issue with Cosmos DB where the behavior of a query with `{upsert: true}` and [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert) where the *insert* values are applied every time regardless of if the operation was an insert or an update.

The results of the following example query when ran against Cosmos DB and MongoDB show a difference in the final value of `defaultQty`.

```
db.products.remove({})
// WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })

db.products.insert({ _id: 1, item: "apple", price: 0.05, defaultQty: 50})
// WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

db.products.find({})
// { "_id" : 1, "item" : "apple", "price" : 0.05, "defaultQty" : 50 }

sleep(100)
db.products.update(
    { _id: 1 },
    { $set: { price: 0.10 }, $setOnInsert: { defaultQty: 100 }},
    { upsert: true }
)
// WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })

db.products.find({})
// { "_id" : 1, "item" : "apple", "price" : 0.1, "defaultQty" : 100 }
```

Here is a screen shot of the [comparison results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Neurz.png) side-by-side in Studio 3T.

Has anyone experienced this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue that will be fixed shortly in Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any official channel/change log to check and see if this issue is addressed later on?

Comment: In general, you can create an item on User Voice (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api) so that it can get voted on and then you can see when it's in development/fixed. However the fix is already in process on this one. Should be available by the end of the month.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is now fixed awaiting deployment. You can track progress here  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/599059-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api/suggestions/20017141-bug-fix-during-upsert-operation-setoninsert-is-b

We Will post update once deployment is completed.

thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: You can just add this as a comment.

Comment: I can confirm that our tests pass, this appears fixed! Thank you!